# can not having a PTR record affect website performance?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I moved my ptr from my maindomain.com to my mail.maindomain.com. Now i could swear my website was faster before, but i can't prove it. Could not having a PTR record affect performance in any way? Maybe there's apps that do a callback somehow?

Comment: Seems unlikely client-side given the prevalence of name-based virtual-hosting (ie  PTR(A(name)) != name). Perhaps something server-side might explain it; does the server have a mapping for itself in /etc/hosts ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't affect. You have done correctly, since `PTR` records are nowadays only commonly used by spam filters for detecting poorly configured servers; with `PTR mail.example.com` you are avoiding `A` != `PTR` != `HELO` hostname mismatch. The only requirements for `PTR` record itself is that there must be only one `PTR` record per IP address and it should have the corresponding `A` record.

The HTTP protocol isn't interested in any of the above. Only record needed is the `A` record, and the hostname doesn't come from `A` nor `PTR` but from `Host:` header sent by the browser.

You haven't specified the web server (e.g. Apache / Nginx / IIS) you are using. For Apache, there is only one condition where it uses reverse DNS, and that is a onetime query on startup in a special condition related to [Name-based Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html); it doesn't affect site performance at all:

> If a [`VirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) doesn't specify a [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername), a server name will be
>   inherited from the base server configuration. If no server name was
>   specified globally, one is detected at startup through reverse DNS
>   resolution of the first listening address. In either case, this
>   inherited server name will influence name-based virtual host
>   resolution, so it is best to always explicitly list a ServerName in
>   every name-based virtual host.

Then, "Apps" on your website could be anything from common *content management systems* to custom scripts by you or your customers. They could do anything, making this way too broad to answer. One example could be that some of the Apps is using `PTR` records for detecting originating country based on the TLD. That information could be used for statistics or access control. This could cause performance problems, but it would also be ineffective and give false information. It should be replaced with querying a local database for GeoIP information. However, this would cause `PTR` queries for client IP addresses, not the server itself, and thus isn't related to your conditions, either.

Comment: Thank you Esa. It turned out to be more of a caching plugin that seems to have significant effect on gtmetrix.com